# Remove parts of a video automagically without reencode?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm looking for a way to remove automatically the opening and ending parts of a video (credits) without reencode.

If you need an example, take Game of Thrones : I'd need a way to automatically remove the GoT opening (with the theme music) and the ending part (with the credits and the HBO logo part).

FFmpeg can do that, but the cut has to be manual and happens only at keyframes... which isn't precise enough for me.

I thought that maybe there is a tool that allows to scan a video, and remove a part between two input frames (the start of opening frame, the end of opening frame)... etc, same thing for Ending.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: So, you'd want to delete the first 11 minutes of Up; the first 19 minutes of Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind; and the first 143 minutes of Inception?

Comment: I have multiple video files with the same intro/outro (visual and audio).
My thought is that there were, maybe, a tool that would use an input of the start frame and end frame of that section, and then remove the middle part. 
Or maybe, one that would've audio recognition to match audio from a pre-recorded mp3 to these videos, and delete the matched section.

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this? Plex has skip intro abilities, makes me think deleting intros should be doable.

Comment: I wish I had found something, but sadly nope .. Though, I'm sure it'd be possible to detect a same portion of video (like the start and end points of an intro) and trim it. 

But well...